# Text and Image together in a fixed width overflowing-column component in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextview, richtextblock

I want to combine text and images in a view (not using `UIWebView`) and I want to make the content appear according to the width of the inner view predefined by me. If it's content overflows the content size of that inner view, I want it to overflow to the next view (column right next to the previous one).

Summary: I want to combine both text and images like a newspaper page; fixed width columns all next to each other.

I am trying to create a custom `UIScrollView` but it becomes more complex in every step and I don't feel safe about this method.

I am using `RichTextBlock` component in Windows 8 where I can easily add Text or Image objects. I hope to find a similar component but I still haven't.

Are there any other easier methods or ready-to-use libraries made for a similar thing?